# Capybara / Ruby - Trying to return to the beginning of the loop when an error shows up

Tags: ruby, rspec, automated-tests, capybara

I'm trying to return to the loop beginnig when an error shows up as the code below.

I'm using the command "next" when a casual error occurs but it is not coming back for the loop beginning.

```
describe 'Test', :test do

before(:each) do
    visit '/admin'
end


it 'Adding new images' do

    image = 'barcelona.jpg'

    @imagem = Dir.pwd + '/spec/fixtures/' + image

    produto = '1'

    100.times do

        visit '/admin/' + produto

        if page.has_no_css?('#mensagem > h1')

                within_frame(:xpath, "//*[@id='app-content']/main/div/iframe") do

                    find('#ctl00_Conteudo_tbxNome_txtId').set 'test_name'
                    find('#ctl00_Conteudo_BtnSalvar').click

                    if page.has_no_css?('#mensagem > h1')

                        find('#ctl00_Conteudo_tbxIdArquivoControle_lnkInserirArquivo').click

                        attach_file('ctl00_Conteudo_tbxIdArquivoControle_tbxArquivo', @imagem) 
                        find('#ctl00_Conteudo_tbxIdArquivoControle_btnEnviar').click

                        if page.has_no_css?('#mensagem > h1')

                            find('#skuTabNavigation a[href="#tabImages"]').click
                            expect(page).to have_content image

                            puts 'Test ok'

                        else
                            puts 'Error was presented, starting over..'
                            next
                        end

                    else
                        puts 'Error was presented, starting over..'
                        next
                    end
                end
        else
            puts 'Error was presented, starting over..'
            next
        end
    end
end
end
```

I would like that every time when the system goes to "else" condition, it restart the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to move back to the initial iteration of a loop. `redo` exists but it only moves you back to the current iteration.

In this case, you probably want to change the way you're looping so you can more easily control when to start/stop. For example:

```
i = 0

while i <= 100 do
  if page.has_no_css?('#mensagem > h1')
    i = 0
    puts 'Error'
    next
  end

  i += 1
end
```

So you don't have to reset the loop index and call `puts` each time you could rescue an error:

```
class MyError < StandardError; end
i = 0

while i <= 100 do
  begin
    if page.has_no_css?('#mensagem > h1')
      raise MyError, 'thing was missing'
    end

    puts i
    i += 1
  rescue MyError => boom
    puts "Error: #{boom.message}"
    i = 0
    redo
  end
end
```